# Cache Include Files While Developing PHP Script

Tags: php, caching

In the past few days, when I edit a PHP script that is included in another script, the browser is using a cached version and I'm not seeing my changes.

I have tried with no success:

- in Chrome developer tools, "disable cache" on Network tab
- in Chrome developer tools, ctrl-click on refresh and select "empty cache and hard reload"
- adding PHP header() calls with no-store, no-cache, etc.
- shift-refresh in Chrome
- using Safari
- restarted my Docker Ubuntu/Apache sandbox that is "https://localhost"
- passing a unique argument on the URL, e.g. ?junk=1234
- a Chrome extension to clear the cache

I've developed for years without experiencing this problem, and suddenly I can no longer see my changes.

I can't figure out what changed to break it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be a volume caching thing in Docker.